# $\lim_{x\to \frac54\pi} \lfloor\sin x+ \cos x\rfloor$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is Greatest Integer Function, is $-1$ or $-2$? why?

Tags: limits

There's a few questions in limits that I think I got right but my peers have challenged my answers and I have no idea how to solve these limits to get the answers they're getting or if I'm right!!
Here's another :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac 1 {2^r}.$$

Comment: the title is something like $\lim_{x\to \frac54\pi}[\sin x+ \cos x]$?

Comment: Yep. and [.] denotes step of function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\displaystyle L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^r} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}$

Now Let $\displaystyle S = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n} \tag 1$

Multiply both side by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\cdot S = \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \tag 2$

Now $(1)-(2)\;,$ We get

$$ \frac{S}{2} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\Rightarrow S = 1-\frac{1}{2^n}$$

So $\displaystyle L =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right] = 1$

Comment: when you're doing (1)-(2), is that a general formula ?

Answer (score 1):

Given $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{5\pi}{4}}\lfloor \sin x+\cos x\rfloor  = \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{5\pi}{4}} \lfloor \sqrt{2}\cdot\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\rfloor $

Above we can write $\displaystyle \sin x+\cos x = \sqrt{2}\left[\sin x\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cos x\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] = \sqrt{2}\cdot \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

So Let $\displaystyle \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = y\;,$ Then When $\displaystyle x\rightarrow \frac{5\pi}{4}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle y \rightarrow \frac{3\pi}{2}$

So Limit Convert into $\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow \frac{3\pi}{2}}\lfloor \sqrt{2}\cdot\sin y\rfloor $

Now Calculate Left hand limit and right hand limit at $\displaystyle y = \frac{3\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

The functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ are continuous, so for any $\delta >0 $ there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $$|x-5\pi /4|< \epsilon $$ implies  $$| \sin x +\sqrt 2 /2|= |\sin x -\sin 5\pi /4| < \delta$$ and $$|\cos x+\sqrt 2 /2|=|\cos x -\cos 5\pi /4|<\delta$$ which implies $$ -\sqrt 2 -2\delta <\sin x +\cos x < -\sqrt 2 +2\delta.$$ Since $[-\sqrt 2]=-2$  , we have$$[\sin x + \cos x]=-2$$ whenever $|x-5 \pi /4|$ is sufficiently small. E.g. take an $\epsilon$ with $\delta =1/8.$